# Remove all items inside linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I create a linearlayout that refes to an xml item. Inside this linearlayout i put some textview dynamically, so without taking them from the xml. Now i need to remove these textviews from the linearlayout. I tried this:

```
if(((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getParent()).getChildCount() > 0)
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getParent()).removeAllViews();
```

but it doesn't work.
How can i do?
Thanks, Mattia

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Why you wrote `linearLayout.getParent()`?

You should call this directly on `LinearLayout`:

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: no need to add the count check as `removeAllViews()` already does this internally.  
  from  `removeAllViews()` source code `if (count <= 0) { return; }`

Answer (score 4):

Hi Please try this code its working for me

```
public class ShowText extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView textView,textView1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView=new TextView(this);
        textView1=new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("First TextView");
        textView1.setText("First TextView");

        linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mn);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.addView(textView1);
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();

    }
}
```